# Tkinter multiple errors before and after mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter, mainloop

I am making an excel comparing program and exporting it to a CSV file. Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl, csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

output = open('differences.csv', 'w', newline='')
output_writer = csv.writer(output)

wb1, wb2 = '', ''
sheet1, sheet2 = '', ''
column_1, column_2 = '', ''

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='light green')
root.geometry("500x500")
root.wm_title("BananaCell")

e1 = Text(root, width=15, height=1)
e1.pack()
e1.place(x=70, y=150)

e2 = Text(root, width=15, height=1)
e2.pack()
e2.place(x=300, y=150)

column1_entry = Text(root, width=5, height=1)
column1_entry.pack()
column1_entry.place(x=135, y=250)

column2_entry = Text(root, width=5, height=1)
column2_entry.pack()
column2_entry.place(x=385, y=250)


def destroy():
    root.destroy()

def ask_for_filename_1():
    global wb1
    wb1 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 1")
    print(str(wb1))
    return wb1


def ask_for_filename_2():
    global wb2
    wb2 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 1")
    print(str(wb2))
    return wb2


def ask_for_sheet1():
    global sheet1
    sheet1 = e1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(sheet1)
    return sheet1


def ask_for_sheet2():
    global sheet2
    sheet2 = e2.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(sheet2)
    return sheet2


def get_col_1():
    global column_1
    column_1 = column1_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(column_1)
    return column_1


def get_col_2():
    global column_2
    column_2 = column2_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(column_2)
    return column_2


filename_button1 = Button(root, text="Workbook 1", width=12, height=2, command=ask_for_filename_1)
filename_button1.pack()
filename_button1.place(x=100, y=100)

filename_button2 = Button(root, text="Workbook 2", width=12, height=2, command=ask_for_filename_2)
filename_button2.pack()
filename_button2.place(x=300, y=100)

col_button1 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=5, height=1, command=get_col_1)
col_button1.pack()
col_button1.place(x=185, y=248)

col_button2 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=5, height=1, command=get_col_2)
col_button2.pack()
col_button2.place(x=435, y=248)

sheet_button1 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=6, height=0, command=ask_for_sheet1)
sheet_button1.pack()
sheet_button1.place(x=15, y=147)

sheet_button2 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=6, height=0, command=ask_for_sheet2)
sheet_button2.pack()
sheet_button2.place(x=430, y=147)

label1 = Label(root, text="Sheet 1 column letter: ", bg="light green")
label1.pack()
label1.place(x=10, y=250)

label2 = Label(root, text="Sheet 2 column letter: ", bg = "light green")
label2.pack()
label2.place(x=260, y=250)


def write_csv(col1, col2, worksheet1, worksheet2):
    for (col, col_1) in zip(worksheet1.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col1), max_col=column_index_from_string(col1)), worksheet2.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col2), max_col=column_index_from_string(col2))):
        for (cell, cell_1) in zip(col, col_1):
           if cell.value != cell_1.value and cell.row == cell_1.row:
               output_writer.writerow(['Sheet 1 value: ' + ' ' + str(cell.value) + '  ' + 'is not equal to ' + '  ' + 'Sheet 2 value:  ' + ' ' + str(cell_1.value) + ' ' + 'on row ' + ' ' + str(cell.row)])


dButton = Button(root, text="Exit", width=8, height=1, command=destroy)
dButton.pack()
dButton.place(x=100, y=60)


mainloop()

workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb1))
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb2))

global sheet1
sheet1 = e1.get("1.0", "end-1c")

global sheet2
sheet2 = e2.get("1.0", "end-1c")


worksheet1 = workbook1.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet1))
worksheet2 = workbook2.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet2))

col1 = column1_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
col2 = column2_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")

write_csv(col1, col2, worksheet1, worksheet2)
```

However, when I run the follwing code, I enter the criteria required and end up with the following error: `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".71847552"`.
When I put `mainloop()` as the last line of the file, I get this error: `self.fp = io.open(file, modeDict[mode])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''` Can anyone rewrite my code so that it will successfully compile? Any help is great thank you

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

After you destroy the window, which means your code will proceed past `mainloop` you then attempt to reference widgets with the containing master `root` which have been destroyed and their associated methods `get`. This will raise an error if you attempt to do this after the window has been destroyed.

Comment: Can you provide some code that will fix this error?

Comment: Delete all the code after mainloop().  Or move it somewhere before mainloop().

Comment: @TerryJanReedy when I do that I get the following error: `No such file or directory ''`

Comment: Can anyone please help?